# Electronic starter shaft for 49cc engine

Tags: motorcycle, starter

I have a 49cc 2 stroke engine in the following format:

[image]

I also have a 12V electronic starter like this:

[image]

However what I am currently lacking is a bolt/shaft to connect the electronic starter with the engine and gearbox. I have found several locations where I find the apparently appropriate part to buy, however all of them list it as "out of stock" or "discontinued by manufacturer". Here is an example:

https://www.urbanscooters.com/products/electric-starter-bolt-shaft-part-260-26

Does anyone know what the proper name or maybe a number for this part is?

Comment: what is your scooter brand? model? because different manufacture have different model of starter or bolt or shaft. it could damage your scooter if you got wrong parts.

Comment: It is an in-progress DIY project, not for a full scooter. The part linked is (or was) typically sold in bundles for that engine and starter. Also the measurements match what is specified for the starter.

Comment: are you going to install the starter where the pull start is now and are you sure that the starter is made for your engine.

Comment: It goes between the clutch and the motor case like here (the gray block in front of the black clutch): https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB19hpyMFXXXXblXVXXq6xXFXXX4/49cc-2-STROKE-ENGINE-with-electric-start-throttle-cable-comp-MOTOR-MINI-QUAD-ROCKET-POCKET-BIKE.jpg_Q90.jpg

Comment: you have posted pictures of two different motors,is the one in your question the exact type you have or is it the motor type in your comment?

Comment: the one in my question is the exact motor and starter I have.